# F# Recursive function not ending although I think it should

Tags: recursion, f#

I have a recursive function in my code that looks like this:

```
let rec func (a,b)
    match (a,b) with
    | condition 1 -> func a+1 b
    | condition 2 -> print "%s" done
    | _ then func a b+1              //<-- It enters here after going into the else ()!!
    if a = b then func 0 0
    else ()
```

The problem is that when the match section ends, it goes to the if statement and doesn't match it, which is good. So it goes to "else ()" and should quit the recursion but instead it goes back to the `|_ -> print func a b+1`. Why can this happen?

Comment: What behavior do you expect? Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I am so confused by your code. This should not compile for so many reasons. There is no equal sign on the first line. It takes a tupple, but you pass two arguments in the recursion. Your match takes a tupple, but there are no commas in the conditions, the last match does not have a `->` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You effectively have two sections of code

a match statement

```
 match (a,b) with
 | condition 1 -> func a+1 b
 | condition 2 -> print "%s" done
 | _ then func a b+1              //<-- It enters here after going into the else ()!!
```

and then an if/else

```
 if a = b then func 0 0
 else ()
```

Unless "condition 2" is matched, this function will always recurse during the match section and it does not matter that the if/else block does not recurse. I am not sure what you are attempting to achieve, but maybe you want a match/when

```
 match (a,b) with
 | condition 1 -> func a+1 b
 | condition 2 -> print "%s" done
 | _,_ when a = b -> func 0 0
 | _ -> func a b+1              //<-- It enters here after going into the else ()!!
```

Now "condition 2" is your stop case. Is "condition 2" an active pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, after reaching

```
| condition 2 -> print "%s" done
```

then if `a=b` your program continues by doing

```
if a = b then func 0 0
```

(Or maybe it returns, then do the same call higher up the call chain.)
Likely that recursive call then takes you to

```
 | _ then func a b+1
```

Because of lightweight syntax, the `if` after the `match` is always executed.

Comment: So what can I do in order to make it end when it enters to the else()?

Comment: Depends on what you want to accomplish. Could you make the program concrete? Put in real conditions and let us know what it's supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I got where my problem was. The recursion was called N times, so when the recursion ended within the match statement, it had to go N times into the if statement. I don't know why while debugging it would show the `|_ -> else()` highlighted, but I already understood the problem and solved it. Thank you guys!